# Opencv 2.2.0 VS2010C++ webcam grey image only

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm trying to do a simple opencv project to track colour and testing out my webcam at home as the school is crowded whenever I have the time to do my project. However opencv is not correctly using my webcam.

This is an image of the codes I used and the result.

[image]

I really need any help I can get.. The webcam I have is this: http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-webcam-c525

Would really appreciate any help :)

Does having a 64 bit computer make any difference? Because opencv is 32bit

Comment: What do you mean by `However opencv is not correctly using my webcam`?  Also, don't post a screenshot of your code, that's too tiny to read; instead, edit your question to contain the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Try open other cam, may be you have some virtual web cams installed in system. To do this change argument of cvCaptureFromCam to something different from 0.

Comment: I have only one webcam attached.. but i will try that. Okay have tried that.. Becomes worse with nothing happen after some parsing.. sigh

Comment: Looks like your camera not detected by OpenCv. I don't know if it help you, but try change you opencv HAVE_VIDEOINPUT option on/off. It turns on/off DirectShow support. If you turn it off opencv will use Video for Windows (vfw), else  DirectShow. You must rebuild OpenCV after change this option.